# Как получить значение в блоке class

Tags: python, html, requests

У меня есть парсер. Я хочу получить значение, которые лежит в блоке span class.
Для этого я написал такой код

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.tinkoff.ru/invest/stocks/TSLA/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

a = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "Money-module__money_2PlRa"})
print(a)
```

Теперь я хочу получить просто значение 620, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если вас устроит первый попавшийся блок вы можете использовать soup.find(). Тогда вам просто нужно вывести текст найденного блока:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.tinkoff.ru/invest/stocks/TSLA/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

a = soup.find("span", {"class": "Money-module__money_2PlRa"})
print(a.text)
```

Результат:

```
620,6 $
```